# correct way to use dplyr::arrange with dynamic sort by columns

Tags: r, tidyverse

I am trying to figure out how to use the tidyverse to dynamically arrange a dataframe. I used to use arrange_ but this is now deprecated.

Some more specifics. I need to arrange decending if numeric, ascending if not. I have logic for that built in but I can't figure out how to get this to work with arrange.

some data:

```
library(tidyverse)
dat <- tibble(`Project ID` = c(rep("Project A", 3), rep("Project B", 3), rep("Project C", 3)),
                  `Summary Col numeric` = c(50, 50, 20, 500, 500, 200, 3000, 1000, 3000),
                  `Summary Col alpha` = c("A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C"))
```

some code:

```
# set the sort order. Should work either way
sortOrder = c("Summary Col alpha", "Summary Col numeric")


# Problem 1. doesn't work with spaces in names (not essential to fix as 
# I can work around with gsub)

names(dat) <- gsub(" ", "_", names(dat))
sortOrder = gsub(" ", "_", sortOrder)

# get the sort correct - numeric is descending, character is ascending
# figure out numeric cols and paste desc
numericSorts <- sapply(dat[sortOrder], is.numeric) 
sortOrder[numericSorts] <- paste0("desc(",sortOrder[numericSorts], ")")


  # Problem 2 - deprecated solution. Essential to fix
  dat %>% 
  dplyr::arrange_(.dots = sortOrder)
```

Does anybody have a solution using the tidyverse?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can use a solution proposed in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38052325/arrange-multiple-columns-with-descending-order). We need to use both expression from `rlang` and execute this code thanks to `!!` :

```
dat %>% dplyr::arrange(!!rlang::parse_expr(sortOrder[1]),
                       !!rlang::parse_expr(sortOrder[2]))
```

**Edit 1**
This will solve your problem :

```
dplyr::arrange(!!!rlang::parse_exprs(sortOrder))
```

Find [their](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49941362/dplyr-rlang-parse-expr-with-multiple-expressions).

Comment: Thanks. The length of sortOrder could vary. So I can't really rely on magic numbers

Comment: yup, that does it. Thanks!